# Can't retrieve data from Firestore with addSnapshotListener Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two ViewControllers. One is for writing data to Firestore and the other is for loading. Now I can successfully write data, but I can't load it. There isn't any error or data showing up. It seems that the `addSnapshotListener` method was not being called when I tried to observe it with breakpoint. This is my code related with Firestore:

**Updated on July 11**

I tried to print something to check if the code was actually executed, and I got "inside closure" and "Found document." in my console. It seems that it couldn't find `orderDetail` in my Firestore document. However, I indeed have `orderDetail` in each document. Why did this happen?

```
let database = Firestore.firestore()

struct FStore {
    static let collectionName = "orders"
    static let foodID = "foodID"
    static let orderDetail = "orderDetail"
    static let totalPrice = "totalPrice"
    static let timeStamp = "created"
}

    func loadOrder() {
        
        database.collection(FStore.collectionName).order(by: FStore.timeStamp).limit(to: 1).addSnapshotListener { (snapShot, error) in
            
            print("inside closure")  
            self.foodList = []
            
            if let e = error {
                print("There was an issue retrieving data from Firestore. \(e)")
            }
            if let snapShotDocuments = snapShot?.documents,
                let doc = snapShotDocuments.first {

                print("Found document.")

                let data = doc.data()
                if let orderDetail = data[FStore.orderDetail] as? [String: Int] {

                print("Found order detail.")   
                 
// Convert to FoodItem and Append back to foodList
                    for food in orderDetail {
                        let name = food.key
                        let price = food.value
                        let serving = food.value
                        let newFood = FoodItem(name: name, price: price, serving: serving)
                        self.foodList.append(newFood)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                    print("Successfully loaded data from Firestore.")
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

This is the screenshot of my Firestore:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: We need troubleshooting data. First, this does the code inside the closure execute? Add a `print("inside closure")` right after the `.addSnapshot` line and see if it prints. Then, if it does change this code `if let snapShotDocuments = snapShot?.documents` because it's not helpful; if there are no documents the code silently fails (like it is). Does the code after that execute? Add a print and find out.  Same thing here `if let orderDetail = data[FStore.orderDetail] as? [String: Int]` if that fails you won't know it. Add better error handling and update the question with your findings.

Comment: @Jay Printing something does help!  However, there is still something I can't figure out. Please check my question description again.  Thanks.

Comment: First does `FStore.orderDetail` actually have a value? just before `if let orderDetail = data[FStore.orderDetail]` add `print(FStore.orderDetail)` to ensure it's what you expect. Then, looking at your structure, your orderDetail is a.... map? And then within that map each child 1, 2 etc contains an array. That's not going to fit into `[String: Int]` as shown in the question

Comment: You're trying to get `data[FStore.orderDetail]` as `[String: Int]`, but that's not its type in the screenshot you show. It looks like `[String:[String]]`

Comment: I can finally load data successfully from Firestore after fixing the data type. Thank you both so much!